# Is it possible to create a limited registration signup form using Google Docs Forms?

Tags: forms, google-docs, google-apps-script

I would like to create an event signup form using Google Docs. The user is able to select which session they would like to attend, but I need to somehow limit the number of people that can register for each session.

I can not find a way to do this using the standard form creator GUI, however I think it might be possible to do using Google Apps Script. I would need to be able to customize the form that is loaded to remove sessions that are already full based on a query to the underlying spreadsheet.

Is this possible, or should I look into other Web Form surveys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Apps Script Template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/templates) site has some good templates to help you do something like this. In particular, the [Course Registration](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AjbZnjlHMPF0dEtpcTYxRlQ5UlpXZWtiV3JuRDBHYUE&mode=public#) template sounds like what you should use.

Comment: Thanks, it's not the exact answer I was looking for but it was enough to get me started. It would be preferable to have a signup for that only showed the options that are still available though.